# Syntax error in creation of control file

Tags: oracle, shell, sql-loader

I have written a code to create dynamic control file in shell script. When I used `MOD` function  for field `thread_val` I am getting syntax error.

```
   echo 'LOAD DATA' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo 'APPEND' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo 'INTO TABLE TJX_MARKDOWN_AUTHORIZATION' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo 'TRAILING NULLCOLS' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo '(' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo 'FILE_SEQ_NO              "' ${exec_seq} '",' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo 'TRANSACTION_TYPE         position(1),' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo 'WEEK                     ,' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo 'FISCAL_CC_YY             date' \'YYYYMMDD\' ',' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo 'STORE                    ,' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo 'DEPT                     ,' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo 'FROM_PRICE               ,' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo 'TO_PRICE                 ,' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo 'ITEM                     ,' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo 'ESTIMATED_QTY            ,' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo 'STATUS                   CONSTANT "U",' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo 'THREAD_VAL   "(MOD(:STORE, '${max_thread_val)' + 1)"' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
   echo ')' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert `}` after max_thread_val, change `)` position as below;

```
   echo 'THREAD_VAL   "(MOD(:STORE, '${max_thread_val}') + 1)"' >> $CTL_DIR/tjx_markdown_auth_upld.ctl
```